# Did the IMF or World Bank give a public explanation as to why they won't share their debt sustainability analyses with China?

Tags: international-monetary-fund, world-bank

> Expanding this definition should bring into the fold "middle-income"
> countries such as crisis-hit Sri Lanka, which has been seeking debt
> restructuring assurances from China similar to those available to
> "low-income" countries via the G20-led Common Framework.
>
> The world's largest bilateral creditor, Beijing has long wanted
> multilateral lenders such as the International Monetary Fund and World
> Bank to share with it their debt sustainability analyses of those
> seeking debt restructuring, if they expect China to offer debt relief.

https://www.reuters.com/world/china/china-revamps-debt-appraisal-framework-belt-road-programme-2023-10-20/

Did the IMF or World Bank give a public explanation as to why they won't share their debt sustainability analyses with China? I was surprised it didn't share those analyses with China, I thought it would be public. If no such statement was made, did it explain why those analyses aren't made public? I was thinking it might be for the same reason why the Federal Reserve don't share information about which banks are in need of financial assistance.

Comment: https://www.imf.org/en/Publications/Policy-Papers/Issues/2023/06/23/Staff-Guidance-Note-on-Information-Sharing-in-The-Context-of-Sovereign-Debt-Restructurings-535203 That said, what China complains about is not entirely clear because *some* info is public https://www.imf.org/en/Publications/DSA albeit it appears there's some 2-year delay before publication.